# Remove an item from the list with numbers

Tags: python

would appreciate some help here, because I'm out of any ideas.

I have a list of words printed each on a new line with number in front of it. I want to ask user to enter a number and remove that line from the list (using del function). I cannot figure out how to match index and number in front of the line, and avoid it being out of range.

```
linesList = []

def a():
    while True:
        line = input("Add a line: ")
        linesList.append(line)
        if line == "#":
            linesList.pop()
            counter = 0
            for i in linesList:
                print("{}: {}".format(counter + 1, linesList[counter]))
                counter += 1
            print(" ")
            break


def d():        
    while True:
        number = int(input("Line Number: "))
        length = len(linesList)
        if number in range(length):
            del linesList[number]
            counter = 0
            for i in linesList:
                print("{}: {}".format(counter + 1, linesList[counter]))
                counter += 1
            print(" ")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Expected outcome:

```
Add a line: Monday
Add a line: Tuesday
Add a line: Wednesday
Add a line: Thursday
Add a line: Friday
Add a line: #
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
5: Friday

Line number: 5
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
```

Comment: Describe briefly your outcome, please.

Comment: It might be a good idea to pass linesList as a parameter into the functions like so: `def a(linesList): `. Having functions modify global variables is typically seen as bad practice and can make code harder to manage and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the deletion function, the number the user gives is one larger than the index, so you need to adjust your code for that

```
def d():        
    while True:
        number = int(input("Line Number: "))
        length = len(linesList)
        if (number-1) in range(length):
            del linesList[number-1]
            counter = 0
            for i in linesList:
                print("{}: {}".format(counter + 1, linesList[counter]))
                counter += 1
            print(" ")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

With the change:

```
Add a line: Monday
Add a line: Tuesday
Add a line: Wednesday
Add a line: Thursday
Add a line: Friday
Add a line: #
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
5: Friday

Line Number: 5
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
```